The significance of Negative current in a $RL$ circuit
Consider the following question from Pathfinder.

Consider the case $\eta \geq 1$. As the inductor would not allow flux change, $I_0$ current would flow (as initially) and then $(\eta-1)I_0$ would flow through the resistor.
My doubt arises if $\eta < 1$. While the same solution works (negative current in the resistor branch) and satisfies Kirchhoff's Loop rule, what exactly is happening physically?

Someone please help me.
